# Get value of Idless p tags to compare

Tags: javascript, jquery, rdf, sgvizler

I have two columns in html with the following markup:

Column 1:

```
<div id="uni1Query">
<p id="uni1Query1Result" data-sgvizler-chart="sText" data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"><div><p>54.7</p></div></p>
<p id="uni1Query2Result" data-sgvizler-chart="sText" data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"><div><p>34.7</p></div></p>
</div>
```

Column 2:

```
<div id="uni2Query">
<p id="uni2Query1Result" data-sgvizler-chart="sText" data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"><div><p>54.7</p></div></p>
<p id="uni1Query2Result" data-sgvizler-chart="sText" data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"><div><p>34.7</p></div></p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to get the values from column 1 and compare them to same value in column 2.

So what I want is to compare the value of uni1Query1Result with uni2Query1Result and uni2Query1Result with un21Query2Result and so on. I have a third column where the results should be.

What is the best way o do this?

I tried the following:

```
r1 = parseInt($("#uni1Query1Result p").val());
console.log(r1);
r2 = parseInt($("#uni2Query1Result p").val());
console.log(r2);
r3 = (r1 - r2);
alert(r3);
```

But that results in NaN.

Comment: FYI, `.val()` is for getting the value of form fields, not contents of elements.

Comment: @Barmar I seem to have forgotton this. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not nest block level elements within a `<p>` tag, browsers will close the parent `<p>` tag. Checking your console in Chrome will show you that.

Also, you should use `html()` to find the inner value of the tag, and `parseFloat` to find a float number (not an integer)

```
parseFloat($("#uni1Query1Result p").html())
```

Comment: you should use parseFloat, but also you should use your console to check that `$("#uni1Query1Result p")` is pointing at the right element. It should work.

Comment: My guess is that `<div>` is not allowed inside `<p>`, so your `<p id="uni2Query1Result>` does not exist in the dom. Changing `<p>` to `<div>` makes it work: http://jsfiddle.net/BrvRS/4/

Comment: Funny, I had just drawn that conclusion. This is how the p tag works, any block level elements will close the parent p tag. Here is it working http://jsfiddle.net/BrvRS/5/

Comment: @msg your solution works when the data is there but I still get NaN because there is no value yet(sgvizler query not ready) so even with a timeout of 3000 I still get NaN. In the jsfiddle it works because the data is already there in the live envirment it doesnot because the query is still executing i guess.

Comment: @Mild Fuzz your solution works Unfortunatly I seem to have forgotton that there is another p tag in the markup like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BrvRS/6/

Comment: @MildFuzz thanks seems to work. But again in combination with sgvizler I get NaN when I add the value directly to the HTML it does work :(

Comment: could be just a case of event order perhaps? Try taking off the parseFloat, just to see if the HTML has any value at all.

Comment: @MildFuzz removing parseFloat makes it show up undefined in the console

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to pick through that. I just want to know the comment that is returning undefined, and what event is firing that command.

Comment: @MildFuzz yes it works because the data is already added to the html. and not by sgvizler. A live demo of the current situation: http://goo.gl/rT6dD

Comment: I see, well you'll need to either find an event or create one that is being triggered after that value is set

Comment: @MildFuzz i tried it with a set timeout of 10 or more seconds still nothing

Comment: setInterval() is blocking. It doesn't behave the same as an event. You need an event.

Comment: Guys, you know [chat] exists for protracted conversations? This comment thread is getting rather lengthy.

Comment: The problem with chat is you have to be there at the same time!!

Comment: @MildFuzz I tried creating an onclick event with another button but I still get NaN.

Comment: `$("#differenceTitle").on('click',function(){
  alert(parseFloat($("#uni1Title").html())+parseFloat($("#uni2Title").html()));
});`

Comment: I made that code work on your site from the chrome console. Where are you calling it? Put an alert in it to make sure it is being called.

Comment: @MildFuzz I dont get it. Dont we already have an click event? What I want is to do this on click of a button to make sure the data is there before comparing. do I need to us .trigger() when clicked on the button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18299/discussion-between-emrulez-and-mild-fuzz)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach to compare the First value in both the divs

```
$('#uni1Query > p:eq(0) div p').text() == $('#uni2Query > p:eq(0) div p').text()
```

Comment: So what do you want to do with that??

Comment: get value of 1 - value of 2  get a new value and add that to a third column.